# label in navigationitem titleview positioning issue

Tags: ios, label, uinavigationitem, titleview

I am trying to place a label in navigation item title view. In case of long titles,on pushing/popping to other screen, the label moves from its original position and a transition takes place.
The code to set the label:

```
- (void)setNavBarTitle:(NSString *)title {

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 60.0)];
        label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [label setText:title];
        [label sizeToFit];

        self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
        self.parentViewController.navigationItem.titleView = label;
    }
```

Comment: Try  `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth =YES;`

Comment: It doesn't solve the moving of label issue on popping a view.

Comment: @SurbhiGupta: Any specific reasons to add label to the title view? Do you just want to set the screen title or something else is also there?

Comment: @Gandalf: Setting label as I have some long titles to be displayed that get truncated otherwise.